# List of open documents in VisualStudio (Plugin-Development)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in

I am currently trying to develop a simple plugin for visual studio 2008 using c#.

I feel kind of stupid to ask, but after searching the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/za2b25t3%28VS.80%29.aspx) for a few hours I can't find a way for a really simple task: Assume this open solution. I simply want a list of the documents open in the TABs on the right. I tried something, see below...

[alt text http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/5238/20091201172237.png](http://img24.imageshack.us/img24/5238/20091201172237.png)

**This approach is not working:**

[alt text http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/6571/20091201172211.png](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/6571/20091201172211.png)

**And the result is rather strange:**

[alt text http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/6535/20091201172247.png](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/6535/20091201172247.png)

Any tips on how to list the active documents?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I just found a way around the ugly DTE. Its simply not using it :-) At least not directly. I found DxCore, which is free (at least for personal use, I guess) and does the job quite nicely.

To get what I wanted, I simply needed this code (which was what I was hoping in VS for, but there it kind of behave different)...

[alt text http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/7127/20091201221414.png](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/7127/20091201221414.png)

Answer (score 1):

Can't answer your specific question, but can make a couple of comments/suggestions:

- The DTE object model is ugly, ugly, ugly - you're not the only person who's struggled with it (ask me how I know).
- Ask your question on the [Visual Studio Extensibility Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/threads) - they can probably help.

Comment: Thanks, after looking around in the forum a little bit, I chose a different approach. Only need it for some little helper plugin for me, so I simply use DxCore...

Comment: Either DxCore was not available last year when I had my brief and unhappy exposure to the DTE, or I somehow missed it.  Looks promising...